# Cannot turn off noise cancelling on Bluetooth headphones

Tags: switches, power-electronics

I recently dropped my Mixcder E9 headphones. These headphones have active noise cancelling.  After being dropped, the noise cancel switch stopped working and the active noise cancelling is always on.

I would like to either fix the switch or permanently turn off the noise cancelling. When I opened up the device I could not see how the slider switch worked and could not turn off the noise cancelling. There didn't seem to be any loose or broken internals.

[image: Switch on device]

[image: Switch slider]

[image: Circuit]

[image: Switch highlighted in circui]

[image: Side view of switch]

Comment: Remove the switch wires and test with an Ohmeter to see if it actually works. If it does, then the damage is elsewhere and probably not recoverable.

Comment: I don't see how that plastic slider would have an effect on the switch. Are you sure the switch is not supposed to have a moving part?

Answer (score 5):

This thing is a switch:

[image]

It should have a little nub that is moved by this thing:

[image]

[image]

The little gray piece that the red arrow is pointing to is what is left of the nub:

[image]

The nub seems to have broken off when you dropped the headphones.

Use a pointy object (the point of a pocket knife blade or similar) to push the gray thing to the right.  There's a little black spot to the right - that's where the gray thing needs to go.  Push the gray thing to the right and there will be a black spot to the left. That should turn off the noise canceling function.

Comment: If you can identify the switch, and have access to a soldering iron, it may be possible to get a replacement and fix it. Whether that's worth it is up to you. ("you" referring to djval, not JRE)